# Call multiple dispatch after getting axios response Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I need to call multiple dispatches after getting the response from axios how can I do, it the current way I'm doing is only allowing me to send one dispatch and when trying to fire the second dispatch it gives and error saying that the res is not found.

```
export const getItem = (id) => dispatch =>{
    dispatch(setLoading);
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/getItem?id=${id}`)
    .then(
        res => dispatch({
            type: GET_ITEM,
            payload: res.data
        })
    )
}
```

I need to fire a secondary dispatch after getting the response, the functionality of the secondary dispatch, I need to this after getting the return from axios is because a unique email and id is stored in the response, so I need to get the id, from the response to fire the secondary call.

```
export const getUserItem = (payload) => dispatch =>{
    dispatch(setItemsLoading);
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/getUserItems?email=${payload.email}&id=${payload.id}`)
    .then(
        res => dispatch({
            type: GET_USER_ITEM,
            payload: res.data
        })
    )
}
```

Is there a way to dispatch 2 after a response is received from axios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With arrow syntax you need to add brackets if you want to do more than a single statement:

```
export const getItem = (id) => dispatch =>{
    dispatch(setLoading);
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/getItem?id=${id}`)
    .then(
        res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ITEM,
                payload: res.data
            })
            //second dispatch
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ITEM,
                payload: res.data
            })
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked, I actually did the same and added a ```,``` before the second dispatch which crashed the app :)

Comment: Hi @Marques. You can't add a comma before the second dispatch. Think that dispatch is a function. What you can add is a semicolon at the end of the first dispatch to separate it visually from the second one, just like you could do with any other function.